# Best way to call a python script from within a python script multiple times

Tags: python, import, subprocess, popen

I need to execute a python script from within another python-script multiple times with different arguments.
I know this sounds horrible but there are reasons for it.
Problem is however that the callee-script **does not** check if it is imported or executed (if __name__ == '__main__': ...).

1. I know I could use subprocess.popen("python.exe callee.py -arg") but that seems to be much slower then it should be, and I guess thats because Python.exe is beeing started and terminated multiple times.
2. I can't import the script as a module regularily because of its design as described in the beginning - upon import it will be executed without args because its missing a main() method.
3. I can't change the callee script either
4. As I understand it I can't use execfile() either because it doesnt take arguments

Comment: Can you modify the "callee-script"?

Comment: Replace the script with a proper wrapper, that has the same functionality, but calls methods or classes from your original script.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution for you. You can reload a module in python and you can patch the sys.argv.

Imagine echo.py is the callee script you want to call a multiple times :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# file: echo.py

import sys
print sys.argv
```

You can do as your caller script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# file: test.py 
import sys
sys.argv[1] = 'test1'
import echo
sys.argv[1] = 'test2'
reload(echo)
```

And call it for example with : python test.py place_holder

it will printout :

```
['test.py', 'test1']
['test.py', 'test2']
```

Comment: Note this is on python 2.7, for python 3 use the module imp and imp.reload